# Using X and Y positions from different tuples as input \

Tags: python, simplecv, blobs

I need to use the x and y positions of two separate tuples as a single tuple in order to input it into the next part of my code, any help is appreciated.

```
img1 = Image('img1.jpg')
blobs1 = img1.findBlobs()
if blobs1:
    print blobs1
else:
    print ERROR

img2 = Image('img2.jpg')
blobs2 = img2.findBlobs()
if blobs2:
    print blobs2
else:
    print ERROR
```

This prints two lines

```
[SimpleCV.Features.Blob.Blob object at (500, 600) with area 50]
[SimpleCV.Features.Blob.Blob object at (200, 800) with area 67]
```

How can I use the X position of the first line and the Y position of the second line as the X- and Y-positions of a new tuple, to obtain the color at the new XY position in a different image?

```
pixcol = Image('img.jpg')
colrgb = pixcol[ 'new XY tuple' ] 
print colrgb
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDITED

use *blob*.coordinates()

```
pixcol = Image('img.jpg')

tup1 = pixcol.findBlobs().x # tup1 = X
tup2 = pixcol.findBlobs().y # tup2 = Y

colrgb = pixcol[(tup1,tup2)] # insert the tuple
print colrgb
```

So in your real code, you'd have:

```
...
if blobs1:
    tup1 = blobs1.x
...
if blobs2:
    tup2 = blobs2.x
...
pixcol = Image('img.jpg')
colrgb = pixcol[(tup1,tup2)]
print colrgb
```

Comment: I keep getting error no attributr 'split', also I am not manually inputting the X and Y positions from the 2 lines of printed code, is there a way to extract these two points automatically. Thank you.

Comment: Okay, I read up a bit and it seems like you can get the coordinates easily: use *blob*.coordinates(). I'll try editing my answer with that.

Comment: @HansVK awesome. I figured there was something like that but SimpleCV's documentation doesn't really exist. Thanks for digging into this

Comment: Unfortunately I am recieving the error 'IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for 0 with size 1

Comment: I have no idea what's going wrong there... Are you sure there's only 1 item blobs2...? As in, are there maybe multiple blobs in img2.jpg?

Comment: Agh I knew it was probably this simple: the x and y are stored in variables: *blob*.x and *blob*.y

Comment: Yes there is only ever one blob per pic. Thanks for the help, beginner here.

Comment: Same here :) nice working with ya. -- also, it works now, right?

Comment: You too, it is now returning an integer is required :/ (in colrgb)

Comment: ehm does changing "pixcol[tup1,tup2]" to "pixcol[(tup1,tup2)]" fix it?

Comment: colrgb returns a tuple with .0 after each value(12.0, 145.0, 133.0). If this might be a problem..

Comment: I don't think it'll be a problem. Have fun mate!